# удаление записи из базы через определенное время

Tags: php, mysql, modx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать удаление записей из таблицы через определённое время. Знаю варианты через cron и с помощью запроса в момент выборки записей. Но, не пойму, что менее ресурсозатратнее для базы. Или же это зависит от частоты запросов выборки? А, может, применить оба метода? Только крон раз в сутки запускать, чтоб чистил старые записи, к которым давно не было запросов выборки?

Comment: [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html). Но удаление информации - вообще-то неумное действие. Или помечайте её как невалидную, или перемещайте в архив.

Comment: Так то оно так... Но а если мне не нужна больше эта информация, и она только место в базе занимает? Мало вероятно, что мне захочется узнать когда некий пользователь подписывался на какой-то ресурс сайта. Намного необходимей знать актуальную информацию.

Comment: Ну нет так нет, удаляйте. Но в любом случае разумнее использовать имеющийся встроенный штатный планировщик, чем прикручивать внешний...